# Will var result = function() { //doSomething }; if (result != null) {//doSomething } force synch code execution?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering on how to force javascript code to execute synchronously on my own withouth a plugin.

Would the Browser wait until the following variable has a value in order to proceed with the rest of the code?
**EDITED :**

```
  var result = (function() { /*doSomething*/ }) ();
```

Since it can be tricky to test this with a debugger maybe one of you know if this can be achieved or not.

Thanks.

Comment: XY problem. What is your actual goal? You usually do not want synchronous stuff in JS.

Comment: not sure why would your example be synchronous... you're just defining function and naming a pointer to that function `result`

Comment: Can you please define "synchronous"? Also, you never actually *execute* the function, you are just *defining the function*. Can you post a more complete code example, preferably not in the title?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Perhaps a link explaining the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/215154 "What is the XY problem? - Meta Stack Overflow") would be more helpful to the OP.

Comment: I made a mistake on my code, I actually meant assigning a variable to a self invoking function. And I am working with a massive javascript only application so synchronity come in handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will only store the function inside the variable, giving you the possibility to call that function latter by doing something like this :

```
var result = function() { // BLABLABLA //};
result(); // Calling the function
```

If you want a self invoking function, you can do this:

```
var result = (function(){ // BLABLABLA // })();
```

What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I am looking for a self invoking function that would block the execution of anything coming after.

Comment: But block until when ? If you use a infinite loop, it will freeze the execution of other javascript code. You should probably take a look at callback functions. What is it you exactly want to do ?

Comment: block until the end of execution

Comment: Until the end of the execution of the function ? So yes, it will work. What will your function do ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a self-invoking function. It looks like this.

```
var result = (function(){ /* do something */ }());

// Or...

var result = (function(){ /* do something */})();
```

This will execute the function immediately and assign the return value to `result`.

Comment: If I then add a condition like if (result !=null) { } will this wait for the self invoking function to fill the variable and only then execute this condition?

Comment: Yes, the function will immediately execute and assign its return value to `result` before continuing to the next statement.

Comment: The "if (result !=null) { }" statement is useless. The execution will stop until the self-invoking function is executed.

Comment: It's not useless at all. Using the return value of a function to conditionally execute statements seems pretty standard to me.